# SPA Implicit Flow vs Authorization Flow vs Hybrid Flow

Tags: api, security, token, single-page-application, openid

There seems to be a consensus about using the OpenId Implicit Flow for SPA(s) although there are some security concerns, does using HTTPS mitigate that risk or it's safer to go with another flow type? e.g. Authorization or Hybrid flow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think the risk is higher if you use Authorization or hybrid flow for SPA, for Hybrid and authorization code you have to keep a secret code that is shared between identity provider and clients which is very risky in case of SPA. because it is a refresh token that can be used to get new tokens if stolen

you know refresh token live longer that access_token, so it's better to provide an access token (implicit flow) with 1 hour for expiration rather than giving a refresh token that lives longer and can be used get new token

Comment: But you don’t need to store secret at SPA side. It’s stored on the server which provides API for the SPA.

Answer (score 1):

The standard now for SPAs is using authorization code flow with PKCE. This allows you to request long-lived tokens (refresh_token) using dynamic secrets via PKCE.

https://oauth.net/2/pkce/

https://youtu.be/CHzERullHe8

Comment: Thanks for adding this, appreciate it!